# Show a map of map data in table format in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, pageblocktable, repeat

I have a map called configMap. it is of type `Map<String, Map<String, List<A__c>>>` where it implies like `Map<Obj, Map<Rec, List<A__c>>>`. 
Just for understanding I have put obj and rec here.

I need to show the data in a vf page in below format.

```
**Obj 1**

   **Rec 1**

   Table shows List<A__c> data for Rec 1

   **Rec 2**
   Table shows List<A__c> data for Rec 2


**Obj 2**

   **Rec 1**
   Table shows `List<A__c>` data for Rec 1
```

To achieve this I am trying below approach that fails to print the data.

```
       <apex:repeat value="{!SetofObjectNames}" var="obj">
        {!configMap[obj]}
         <apex:repeat value="{!SetofRecordTypes}" var="rec"> 
          <apex:column value="{!configMap[obj][rec]}"/>
         </apex:repeat>
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

It gives no error. Simply prints ID value for the records of that List.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: If you want to display name for instance, you should do  `<apex:column value="{!configMap[obj][rec].Name}"/>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this approach might work for you.

Prepare the map and list as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<A__c>>> objectMap {get;set:}

//it will hold the keys like Obj1, Obj2
public List<String> lstObject {get;set;}
lstObject = objectMap.keySet();

//it will hold Rec1 of Obj1, Rec2 of Obj1
public List<String> innerMapKeys {get;set;}

public Map<String, List<A__c>> innerMap = new Map<String, List<A__c>>();

for(String : lstObject)
{
    innerMap = objectMap.get[str];
}
innerMapKeys = innerMap.keySet();
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstObject}" var="obj">
    {!obj}
     <apex:repeat value="{!innerMapKeys}" var="rec"> 
        {!rec}
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!innerMap[rec]}" var="innerRec">
            <apex:column value="{!innerRec.Field__c"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```